# Is drupal well suited for a Real Estate web site?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

this is a simple question. I have to develop a Real Estate website and i'm trying some alternatives.

Have you ever try to develop a Real Estate on Drupal? Have you any concrete thought about how could it be done?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What kind of capabilities do you envision your site to need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear from your question what capabilities or features you want in your Drupal site. That said, I'm guessing its unlikely that you're going to be needing something revolutionary for this real estate site of yours. Drupal should definitely fit the bill. It has about 2000+ modules if you ever want to add some kind of functionality to your site that doesn't come with the bare version of Drupal.

Check out http://www.drupalsites.net/categories to see the different kinds of sites that have been made in Drupal.

I searched for "real estate" at www.drupalsites.net and these are the hits I got:

- http://www.drupalsites.net/weblink/gary-feldman-aspen-real-estate
- http://www.drupalsites.net/weblink/real-estate-il-castello-di-tara
- http://www.drupalsites.net/weblink/gc-residential-real-estate
- http://www.drupalsites.net/weblink/las-vegas-real-estate

See http://www.drupalsites.net/search/node/real%20estate for more results.

I disagree with one of the commenters above.

> If you want to go further than that and add custom functionality, I would steer clear of drupal. Don't try and make it into something it wasn't designed for, it will be in your way.

Thats not true. The fact that there are thousands of modules; many stretching Drupal in ways that no one could have ever imagined *means* that the system is extremely flexible and extensible. *Any* system, however well designed, will get in the way *sometimes* but most of the time it will be a godsend and prevent you from re-inventing the wheel.

I'd start out with a Drupal distribution like Acquia Drupal ( http://acquia.com/downloads ). It is the same as normal Drupal but comes pre-packaged with commonly used modules. It will help you choose from the standard modules used in the Drupal industry.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is for people to put up content and have some views it's fine and dandy. It's a CMS after all, that's what they were made for.

If you want to go further than that and add custom functionality, I would steer clear of drupal. Don't try and make it into something it wasn't designed for, it will be in your way.

My personal opinion on that subject matter, but since your question is subjective, I think it's ok ;)