# Is drupal appropriate for my web application?

Tags: drupal

First a little context for my question. Although I am not new to programming (I have a first class degree in Computer Science) I have been out of it for over ten years. To update myself on the current workflows I am building some distinct systems in different environments (currently looking at LAMPS and Ruby on Rails).

I am building an admin site for my brother's property management company. The design seems pretty straight forward.

I need a database with tables to store:

Estates.
Each estate has a number or properties (flats or houses).
Each property has a number of charges (service charge, water bills, maintenance ect.)

Then I have:
Owners.
Each Owner must have ONE or MORE properties. 
Owners make payments.
Each payment is allocated to ONE or MORE charges.

This is the basic idea, with functionality built on top. Intuitively these tables should be created in, say, mySQL and then CRUD functionality coded in php with html forms.

I feel up to the challenge of web development. I can build a nice little app for my brother to replace his HORRENDOUS spreadsheet :) What I am not is a web DESIGNER. So I thought I would turn to drupal to add bells and whistles, thinking it would let me build a database and put nice looking forms in front of it.

As far as I can see, I don't interact with the mySQL database. I know I can, but the idea in drupal is that the structure above would be designed as content types, not tables, and the interaction is done through views of nodes created through 'create content' forms. As I understand it, content types will store each FIELD in the content type (represented my tables above) as a different table in the database. So I go from a quite simple design to a huge relational structure with a lot of joins.

Looking about on the drupal.org site I also see that building the relations between the content types is not a core function and seems to be implemented by the developer. This means I would be working hard to replicate functionality that comes with the mySQL database server, which seems strange as the nodes are stored using mySQL.

What I gain is the interface design. User login and authentication, web interface, themes ect. Also, in doing this I will learn a bit about drupal and so will have it as an available solution in the future.

My question then is this (at last I hear you cry!). Am I misunderstanding the drupal methodology? Is the system I am using as a case study too simple to benefit from a CMS/CMF? In other words should I just build it using LAMPS and find another framework for making the interface pretty and handling login/authentication and security (and if so do you have any suggestions?)

I would appreciate your opinions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are various modules that provide for relationships between content, the simplest of these is entity reference.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll take a look at the entity reference module. However, the question was not whether it is possible, I know it is possible, I was asking why do it when you can build the database directly and have this functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Drupal is well suited for your requirement. Definitely it is better than creating something from scratch for site that is going to use CRUD and referencing.

It would be good to spend some time researching for drupal modules and [distributions](https://drupal.org/project/project_distribution) for the functionality you are looking for. e.g. for real estate common requirement drupal(dot)org/project/real_estate

As said above, entity reference is helps creating references between content, organic groups provide personal spaces to users and so on.

Another favorable aspect of using Drupal is that it is quite flexible and would be able to accommodate any requirements that come along with time.

On the negative front, you might need to learn Drupal doing the right way which needs some effort climbing a relatively steep learning curve in comparison with some other CMS around.

Also, checkout the answer here [Is drupal well suited for a Real Estate web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852493/is-drupal-well-suited-for-a-real-estate-web-site)

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like it could be a good case study for me to learn drupal. Thanks for the links, I will do the research (I also have a book, Pro Drupal 7 development) and get stuck in. I will give some feedback on the benefits I see from this approach as they arise. Thanks for responding, Happy Holidays :)

Comment: I personally prefer to play around to learn things and in Drupal, would sincerely suggest that. Concepts like hooks, templates, theme structure in theory sounds more complex than it actually is.
Anyways you can reach me on twitter @fotuzlab for anything regarding Drupal. I'll be happy to help.